# I need help decoding this, is this json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is this json? I need to echo certain info out of this and having trouble doing it. I have tried json_decode, and it doesn't seem to work.

```html
a:4:{s:5:"entry";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:10:"individual";}s:5:"group";a:1:{s:6:"family";a:0:{}}s:5:"image";a:3:{s:6:"linked";b:1;s:7:"display";b:1;s:4:"name";a:4:{s:9:"thumbnail";s:19:"jim12_thumbnail.jpg";s:5:"entry";s:15:"jim12_entry.jpg";s:7:"profile";s:17:"jim12_profile.jpg";s:8:"original";s:18:"jim12_original.jpg";}}s:4:"logo";a:3:{s:6:"linked";b:1;s:7:"display";b:1;s:4:"name";s:14:"jim12_logo.jpg";}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
$decode = unserialize('a:4:{s:5:"entry";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:10:"individual";}s:5:"group";a:1:{s:6:"family";a:0:{}}s:5:"image";a:3:{s:6:"linked";b:1;s:7:"display";b:1;s:4:"name";a:4:{s:9:"thumbnail";s:19:"jim12_thumbnail.jpg";s:5:"entry";s:15:"jim12_entry.jpg";s:7:"profile";s:17:"jim12_profile.jpg";s:8:"original";s:18:"jim12_original.jpg";}}s:4:"logo";a:3:{s:6:"linked";b:1;s:7:"display";b:1;s:4:"name";s:14:"jim12_logo.jpg";}}')
```

and then

```
print_r($decode);
```

to have informations about the object

**EDIT:**

it's just an array and you can access it's information this way:

```
$decode['image']['name']['thumbnail']
```

in this example, you'll get the thumbnail value

Comment: That worked for that, now I need to echo out certain info, example I need to echo out this so I can use it [thumbnail] => jim12_thumbnail.jpg